# Принципы тестирования Web Api

Tags: .net, юнит-тесты, webapi

Подскажи, каким образом тестируется WebApi?

Я правильно понимаю, что просто берется какой-нибудь `RestSharp` и шлются запросы к API? Или есть какие-то более продуктивные варианты?

Comment: а что именно Вы хотите протестировать? ответ от сервера? можно протестировать метод возвращающий результат до web-api. может внесете чуть больше конкретики что именно вы хотите сделать

Comment: @Bald По идее, еще и маршруты нужно потестировать => все таки тестированием самих методов не ограничиться, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов тестирования. Например такие:

1. Через Visual Studio - ввод команд в Package Manager Console.

Для тестирования GET-запроса на получение списка объектов от контроллера - ввести команду:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:51396/api/users -Method GET
```

Для тестирования POST запроса необходимо передать объект в формате json с указанием дополнительной информацией:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:51396/api/users -Method POST -Body (@{name = "Bob"; age = "35"} | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

2. Используя Fiddler. Например:

   ```
   POST http://gaia/api/CodeMakor/
   User-Agent: Fiddler
   Host: gaia
   Content-Type: application/json
   {
   "gdbOldFullPathOnServer":"\\\\netapp1\\mapi_pc\\SDE.gdb",
   "appR_VER":1,
   "userName":"borisd"
   }
   ```
3. Используя C# код в любом приложении.
   Например:

Тот же класс модель что и на сервере:

```
    CodeMakorModel model = new CodeMakorModel();
    model.GdbOldFullPathOnServer = "\\\\netapp1\\mapi_pc\\SDE.gdb";
    model.APPR_VER = 1;
    model.UserName = "borisd";
```

HttpClient:

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://gaia"); // "http://localhost:12567/"
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(@"http://gaia/api/CodeMakor", model); // "api/CodeMakor"
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string v = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

О каком именно [тестировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) речь? Их же много видов.

Я бы выделил три минимально необходимых:

- Модульное - тестируем методы контроллеров, вызывая их напрямую (плюс моки/стабы и т. п.). Каждый разработчик прогоняет юнит-тесты перед коммитом в репозиторий.
- Интеграционное - тестируем API запросами. Эти тесты прогоняются билд-сервером перед деплоем на хостинг.
- Нагрузочное - долбим API большим количеством запросов. Выполняется специальной утилитой. Запуск может делаться как вручную, так и билд-сервером.

Еще бы я отметил юзабилити-тестирование и тестирование документации: понятно ли другим людям, как работать с нашим API (ух, с этим бывали проблемы). Это делает, естественно, человек (не из числа разработчиков и проектировщиков).